# Is advertising a post on a different SE crossposting

Tags: discussion

Suppose I post a question whose body consists of a link to a math.SE question and then I proceed to ask "I want to know what economists think about this?"

Is this crossposting? Technically most of the information is located in one place, the math.SE question, but then what is the point of my post here? Should it even be answered here? Wouldn't that result in the same inefficiences as crossposting?

Does it make it worse if I put a bounty on my advertising question?

Comment: I think its ineffective. I'd close the questions of this sort.

Comment: Setting aside the issue of crossposting, "what do economists think about X" is, in general, probably not a very good question for a Stack Exchange site. It seems primarily opinion-based, and it's not really clear what it's specifically asking. The question may just be badly worded, but otherwise, it'd probably end up being closed for that reason even if it didn't have a link to a Q&A on a different site in the body of the post.